# Update Object values inside a document in firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update the object inside a document.

[image: Databse image]
As you can see in the picture above under **TransactionMap**, **Deposit** object is there and inside Deposit one object is there with key value pair. So i want to keep adding object inside **Deposit** Object field. Right now what is happening when i am trying to update it, it gets replaced by the new one, its not getting updated.
Here is the code:

```
const transactionMapDocRef = db
        .collection("users")
        .doc(paymentData.notes[0])
        .collection("Transactions")
        .doc(currentDate);
      try {
        const doc = await transactionMapDocRef.get();
        if (!doc.exists) {
          console.log("No such document!");
          transactionMapDocRef.set({
            TransactionMap: {
              Deposit: {
                [paymentData.notes[1]]: data,
              },
            },
          });
          console.log("Successfully saved");
          return res.status(200).json({ message: "Successfully saved" });
        } else {
          transactionMapDocRef.update({
            TransactionMap: {
              Deposit: {
                [paymentData.notes[1]]: data,
              },
            },
          });
          console.log("Successfully Updated");
          return res.status(200).json({ message: "Successfully Updated" });
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error getting document", err);
        return res.status(500).json({
          message: "Something went wrong!",
        });
      }
```

Please help. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
          transactionMapDocRef.set({
            TransactionMap: {
              Deposit: {
                [paymentData.notes[1]]: data,
              },
            },
          });
```

which replaces the entire document, you will need to use `update()` along with Firstore's dot notation to indicate which specific field value you are trying to change.

```
          transactionMapDocRef.update({
            [`TransactionMap.Deposit.${paymentData.notes[1]}`]: data
          });
```

Comment: Its not working.  And set method is working fine if "TransactionMap" object is not there but if it is there i want to add multiple objects inside "Deposit" but everytime old one get replaced by the new one inside "Deposit" object. @Doug Stevenson

Comment: i have used like this :- transactionMapDocRef.update({
            "TransactionMap.Deposit": {
              [paymentData.notes[1]]: data,
            },
          }); but still its not working. And what you have suggested it showing syntax error.

Comment: You will have to identify the full path of the item to update, and make that the key of the object you pass.  You can't have any nesting of the object to update.

Comment: Inside the "Deposit" Object(mentioned inside an image) i can't add multiple objects. Thats what are you trying to say??

Comment: No, I'm saying you need to build the path to the field you want to update using the dot notation provided by Firestore. It will be a single string key.

Comment: I have tried dot notation also but still its not getting updated. Can you help me with the code.